# How to display the data inputted through TinyMCE in text but not HTML format?

Tags: python, html, django, tinymce

I'm having problem in displaying data inputted through TinyMCE in text format. Instead, data with HTML format is returned. Some of my toolbar also were not displayed

Followed the django-tinymce docs but it doesn't show how to change the format

custom.js:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  theme: 'advanced',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
  ],
  toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | fontselect | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help',
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
```

models.py:

```
container_description = HTMLField()
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms


container_description = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=TinyMCEWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter description'}))
```

I want to display the datas in text not with html tags and also display my missing toolbar icons

Comment: Where are you displaying that? Can you show _how_ you're attempting to do currently?

Comment: i'm adding a data into the database with tinymce and when i view the data in the database, the datas are with html tags like <p>, <ol> or <li> and etc.